# Safari returns an error on document.getElementById(id).click();

Tags: javascript, web, safari

I was checking the compatibility of my web application in different browsers, and I found out Safari has a problem that other browsers doesn't have. 
I think it must be something that is not supported in Safari

In my code I just wrote this line because I wanted a button that displays some content to be clicked on page load.

```
<script>document.getElementById("openIfRegistered").click();</script>
```

I can't understand why it works in other browsers, but not in Safari. Is there a compatibility problem? If so, is there a way to solve it?

This is the error i receive

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'document.getElementById("openIfRegistered").click()')
```

Comment: Where is this `<script>` tag relative to the `<body>`? Are you waiting for the element to actually exist before trying to find it?

Comment: The script tag is at the end of the page, after all the HTML is loaded, at the bottom of the body tag

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/39gwe6sb/1/. Make a minimal, self-contained HTML page that exhibits the your problem.

Comment: My page is bigger, but the structure is exactly like the one you showed in jsfiddle. This is the reason why it works on Chrome and Firefox, but I can't understand why it doesn't work on Safari too

Comment: it also says "MutationObserver is not supported by your browser." Could this be the reason?

Comment: Without a self-contained example that I can actually run, it's not really possible to debug your code.

Comment: It's finding the element, but it has no `click` method. So either Safari doesn't support this, or you're in some mode like quirks mode that eliminates it. Do you have `<!doctype html>`?

Comment: Looking at some [Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript+safari+element.click%28%29), it seems Safari does not support `.click()`, but there are workarounds.

Comment: @Blender: So you tested that demo in Safari and it worked?

Comment: @SkinnyPete: Yes, that's why I said that it works for me.

Comment: @Blender: Huh, what platform?

Comment: @SkinnyPete: MacOS. Does it not work for you on Safari?

Comment: @Blender: I don't have a MacOS/IOS platform so I can't test, but there are many Google results that say `.click()` isn't supported, but maybe they added it.

Comment: ...does it work if you test without a doctype declaration?

Comment: My program is something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/momentino/es0fgy3m/7/

Comment: @FilippoMomentè: That runs fine for me in Safari. Does it work for you?